# Would Ghost Trap revert a Psion Uncarnate to corporeal form?

Tags: spells, dnd-3.5e, psionics, incorporeal

Would the spell Ghost Trap revert a psion uncarnates incorporeal form if they enter the affected area ? What confuses me is this part of the wording for the ghost trap spell:

> All incorporeal creatures in this field become corporeal.
>   Creatures cannot turn ethereal while in this area, and ethereal creatures cannot become nonethereal while in this field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Yes, it would revert them.

The important wording is already quoted in your question:

> All incorporeal creatures in this field become corporeal.

This is an ongoing effect (that is, it applies to any creature entering the area, not just applying once at the time of casting).  We know this because the spell's area is listed as an "emanation."  From [the SRD](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/magicOverview/spellDescriptions.htm):

> An emanation spell functions like a burst spell, except that the effect continues to radiate from the point of origin for the duration of the spell.

A Psion Uncarnate who is incorporeal (via either the Shed Body or Uncarnate class features) would become corporeal while in the area of a *Ghost Trap* spell, or upon entering its area.  While under its effect, they would lose the benefits described in the [incorporeal subtype](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/typesSubtypes.htm#incorporealSubtype).

They would *not* lose their other benefits from the Psion Uncarnate class.  For instance, you retain the advancement to your manifesting provided by by the class.

The spell text about ethereal creatures has no effect in this case, as an incorporeal Psion Uncarnate is not ethereal.

Comment: Assume likeness explicitly states that the likeness is assumed “while incorporeal,” so yes, the psion uncarnate absolutely would lose it when they become corporeal due to *ghost trap* (or any other cause, including running out of shed body prior to 10th).

Comment: @KRyan You're right!  Clearly I missed that when reading the feature before.